# What file contains my template definition?

Tags: templates

I've just inherited a site that uses ExpressionEngine and CodeIgniter.  I'm very excited about it, but I've immediately found myself at a standstill.

I want to place a tracking script in the footer.  In the index file(and on all other pages), a call is made at the end to `{footer}` .

I don't have access to the CMS side of EE, so I'm just deep inside the cPanel looking through the template PHP files.   Where do I find the declaration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, it is very possible that `{footer}` is global variable or snippet which is not saved into files by default EE methods. So very possible you can find it in DB only (tables _snippets & _global_variables).

Comment: That did it!  I'm going to assume that the contents of templates like `{header}` and `{footer}` are declared from the CMS side, and therefore just dumped into the DB rather than creating a file to call them from.